# How to compile a .java file with imports from .jar using javac?

Tags: java

I need to compile a .java file that imports classes from a .jar file without decompiling the .jar. Javac gives me errors when I compile because it can't find the source code for the classes I want to import. I don't want to have to decompile the .jar just to get the source code for the imports. What I can do to compile them?

Comment: ? Fix the errors perhaps? I'm sorry, but this sounds like an XY Problem, where you ask for a specific solution to a red-herring type problem, when the real fix is to approach the overall problem from a completely different approach.

Comment: I have to decompile the whole .jar because it contains imports that are from the packages in the .jar, just editing the class, nothing else.. :/

Comment: I take it from your use of the word "decompiling" that you do not have access to the original .java source.  So, short of hand crafting  new .class files to insert on the .jar file, (have fun with that!) I don't see a solution besides extracting, fixing, compiling and remaking the .jar

Comment: How are you editing "classes"? What errors does `javac` give you?

Comment: It would really help if you'd tell us in more detail what you're trying to achieve, what the .jar file has to do with any of it, and what errors javac is giving you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to make a few assumptions about what you mean here. First, I'm going to assume that what you want to do makes some sense, even though it's not written particularly clearly. That assumption and your comment leads me to believe that you have a .java file somewhere, that it has some import statements, and that some (or all) of the imported classes are coming from this .jar file.

That's not normally a problem. You don't typically need the source code for, say, java.util.HashMap in order to use one in your own code. All you have to do is make sure that the java compiler can see the .class file for the class you're importing, and it just works.

So now this question reduces to: "How do I get a .jar file on my class path so javac will be able to use it?" So let's say this .jar file is called myjar.jar and your class is called myclass.java. ...

On unix or windows systems you'd type in your command shell

```
javac -classpath myjar.jar myclass.java
```

You'd have to provide the paths to those files if they aren't in the current directory.

There are other ways to do this: the CLASSPATH environment variable (which Oracle doesn't seem to like), or using an IDE like Eclipse or NetBeans. If you need more information about those please let us know.

You could look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/classpath.html#CBHHCGFB (for unix systems) or http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html#CBHHCGFB (for windows systems) to find out more. Don't overlook http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/ as a resource for more information about many java topics.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted! Do you know how I can put 2 files for the classpath though because I need another one?

EDIT: Nevermind, just jar1;jar2 :) Thank you!

Comment: To run the file with jar: `java -classpath myjar.jar: myclass`

Answer (score 0):

Answer for your title question:

> How to compile a .java file to .class without javac?

First solution: You may simply rename `javac` file to something else something like `dragon_compiler`, so now you may compile java files with `dragon_compiler` which is not a `javac`

Second solution: implement your own java compiler and name it as you like, maybe `toastc`

---

You first question in body:

> I need to compile a .java file without decompiling a whole .jar

There is no any relation between compiling a java file and jar files, jar files are kinda bunch of compiled/not-compiled java files.

> just have to edit a few classes and Javac gives me errors, what I can
>   do to compile them?

Honestly didn't got this, but you may get the signature(methods, fields) of any class you like to edit, now create a new class file with the same name and package and implement the class as your business, this is not a very good practice, for some situations it doesn't work.

---

Suggestions:

You may use and give some hand of `Java DJ Decompiler` which tries to decompile compiled classes and jar file, simply copy the code, edit and recompile them, but this tool is not as smart as it should be, but gives some hand.

If you are familiar with reflection api, so this api would give some hand during the runtime.

and the best solution would be finding the source of desired class/jar files, 99% of java libraries are open course, unless you got one from 1%.